# Find the zeros and poles, their orders and the residue at each pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

let $$f(z)={1/(z-1)(z-2)}$$

I know the poles are 1 and 2 of order 1 and using the formula for residue for simple poles will give me $-1$ and $1$. How do i find the zeroes? because i am ending up with $1/0$. I am confused.

Comment: There can't be any zeros when $z$ is finite, but $f(x)\to0$ as $z\to\infty,$ so it has a zero at $\infty.$ But no others. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you know the definition of a zero?

Answer (score 3):

It has no zeros: $\frac1{(z-1)(z-2)}=0\iff1=0$.

Comment: doesn't having poles imply that there are zeroes?

Comment: No. $\frac1z$ has a pole at $0$. Does it have a zero?

Answer (score 1):

$g=(z-1)(z-2)$ is entire$\implies f=\frac{1}{g}$ has no zeros.